# is there a trim function for razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I am outputting data to a table like the following:

```
foreach (var attr in item.attr_type)
{
  <td>
     @foreach (var attrs in attr.attr_value)
     {
       @attrs                            
     }              
</td>                 
}
```

If there a trim function i can put around @attrs because alot of white space is created

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure what type `attrs` is, but:

```
@foreach (var attrs in attr.attr_value)
 {
       @(attrs.ToString().Trim())//should work?                            
 }
```

If it doesn't, you can/should, override `toString()` in your attrs type.

Note: `@(..)` does output an HTML-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Kill formatting

```
foreach (var attr in item.attr_type)
{
<td>
     @foreach (var attrs in attr.attr_value)
     {
@attrs
     }
</td>
}
```